# Select a column of used range excluding header but using specific header as target

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a Macro to select a specific column using Id Header as Target. I won't use the number of column because ID column can change between a spreadsheet and an other. so I used `.find` function.

The final purpose is to copy this col

the error message:

> RunTime Error '1004': Application-Defined or Object defined error.

Thanks a lot for your Help and if you have an other strategy to reach the goal please Share.

```
Sub SelectCol ()

Dim WorkSH As Worksheet 

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim ColToCopy As Range

Dim RowNbr As Long 
Dim ColNbr As Long

Set WorkSh = ActiveSheet 

Set TargetCell = WorkSh.UsedRange.Find ("Id")

TargetCell.Select

Set FirstCell = ActiveCell.Offset( 1,0 ) 

ColNbr = FirstCell.Column

' If Possible I want to remove "c" and replace it with rhe Var "ColNbr"

RowNbr = WorkSh.Cells( WorkSh.Rows.Count, "C"). End(XlUp).Row


'line doesn't work even if I set this cells basically like this Cells(5, 8957) 'Which is very bizzare

Set LastCell = Cells (RowNbr, ColNbr) 

Set ColToCopy = Range ( FirstCell, LastCell ) 

ColToCopy.Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works OK for me.  That said, I cleaned it up a bit:

```
Sub SelectCol()

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim RowNbr As Long

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set TargetCell = .UsedRange.Find("Id")
    If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then
        RowNbr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TargetCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(TargetCell.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(RowNbr, TargetCell.Column)).Copy
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

There are less variables required because I try not to use single use variables.

`With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` makes sure you are working on the sheet you think you are.  Also, it allows this `Set TargetCell = .UsedRange.Find("Id")` instead of the longer

`Set TargetCell = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Id")`.

`If Not TargetCell Is Nothing` tests if `"Id"` has been found because if it's missing `RowNbr` won't be able to be set.  `TargetCell.Column` would = 0.

Answer (score 0):

"Application-Defined or Object defined error" means that there is an error with your objects. In your code you have this:

```
Dim TargetCell, FirstCell, LastCell, ColToCopy As Range
```

It means that the `TargetCell`, `FirstCell` and `LastCell` are declared as variables of type Variant and not Range Objects. To declare them as range objects do this:

```
Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim ColToCopy As Range
```

Comment: Yes it was like this in my macro and it doesn't work. Thnk's for your quick response

Comment: @DataScientist - what is `ActiveWorksheet`?

Comment: @DataScientist - what do you mean - "it was like this in my macro?" You have written it correctly, and then you have made the code worse just to ask a question?

Comment: I mean even with this writing I got the same error message. and this message error refers to this line of code : Set LastCell = Cells (RowNbr, ColNbr)

Comment: hi thanks for ActiveWorkSheet remark.  I will correct it right Know

Comment: @Viyata Still Does not Work for same line: Set LastCell = Cells (RowNbr, ColNbr)

Comment: before that line add Msgbox rownbr & " " & colnbr   and see what your variables are actually holding. Also Set LastCell = Worksh.Cells (RowNbr, ColNbr)